# Passing An Object That Can Be Nil

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call a method and pass two arguments and sometimes one of the arguments can be nil.

```
storeMembershipInfo(photoData, textField.text!)
```

photoData is declared as

`var photoData: Data!`

and can hold data from image picker, but it's not mandatory to have a value.

I get the error found nil while unwrapping an optional. How can I let swift pass photoData even if it's nil? I'm checking the nil case later in the called method, and If I make it optional, swift requires me to force unwrap it.

Comment: How is the storeMembershipInfo function defined? Does it take optional or non-optional parameters? Where/how do you "check the nil case later"?

Comment: Does your storeMembershipInfo method take optional parameters or non optional. Can you add the method declaration code here

Comment: Simple rule: If *one of the arguments can be nil* do **not** use an implicit unwrapped optional. Please read the comprehensive section in the Language Guide about optionals – especially the difference between a regular optional (`?`) and an IUO (`!`) – and how to use them.

Comment: @Martin R, kapsym, you're right storeMembershipInfo didn't take optional as a parameter, now the code works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to change your variable's declaration from:

```
var photoData: Data!
```

To:

```
var photoData: Data?
```

And then change your function signature to become something like this:

```
func storeMembershipInfo(photoData: Date?, text: String)
```

This way your function accepts optionals, which means it can accept `nil` ==> you won't need to unwrap your optional variable `photoData` when you want to send it as a parameter to the function.

Comment: my problem was not letting storeMembershipInfo accepts optional parameter, thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you are declaring a `var` with `!` you basically saying - "this will never be nil". Thats not the case with your code...
If this `var` can hold nil, you should declare it as optional (`?`).

In your function check if is nil or not and continue accordingly, also read more about [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) here